# promise returns undefined in node module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

The Promise returns `undefined` when trying to log it in `routes.js`, however works fine when logging in `queries.js`. How should i change the promise to correctly return a response to `routes.js`?

in `queries.js`:

```
const rsClient = require('./client.js');

const query = {
    one: 'SELECT * FROM my.db'
}

module.exports = {
    rsProdRecs: (req, res) => {
         rsClient.query(query.one)
            .then(res => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
};
```

in `routes.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var queries = require('../queries');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const data = queries.rsProdRecs();
  console.log(data)
  res.send(data);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Note that a promise doesn't "return" anything. Only functions can return something. `rsProdRecs` is a function that returns a promise (if you fix your code as Andry suggests). The promise *resolves* to a value at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code. The first issue has already been pointed out by other users, you need to return the promise from `rsProdRecs`. The `then` and `catch` blocks are also problematic as well as how you are consuming the method in your route, as described in the code below:

```
module.exports = {
    rsProdRecs: (req, res) => {
        return rsClient.query(query.one);

        // This is redundant, you're not transforming res in any way so this can be omitted.
        // .then(res => {
        //     return res;
        // })

        // This will cause the promise to return 'undefined' if rsClient.query(...) rejects,
        // instead error handling should be done in the calling function.
        // .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
};
```

And you can refactor your route to properly consume your `Promise` returning method:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // We cannot consume the "data" directly, we must wait for the promise to resolve.
    queries.rsProdRecs()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500); // insert correct error response here
        });

});
```

Or use `async/await` since you are already using ES6 funcionality:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const data = await queries.rsProdRecs();
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try add `return` statement?

```
rsProdRecs: (req, res) => {
         return rsClient.query(query.one)
            .then(res => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: However, in `queries.js`, if i console.log(res) in .then() it returns the object i'm looking to pass to `routes.js`. In routes.js it returns `{
isFulfilled: false,
isRejected: false
}`

Comment: @alt-rock: That's how promises work. `rsProdRecs` can never return the object, it can only return a promise.